# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")

salary = raw_input("What is your annual salary?")

tax = float(raw_input("What is your tax rate? (Convert it to decimals)"))

vactaion = int(raw_input("How many not paid vacation weeks do you have?"))

hourlypay = salary / ( 52 - vactaion ) * tax / 40 

print " %, your hourly pay after taxes is %." % ( name, hourlypay),
```

Can you please tell me why "hourlypay" has the error.

Answer (score -1):

The `raw_input` function returns a string. You need to cast it to an int or float before you can use it in a math operation like `hourlypay = salary / ( 52 - vactaion ) * tax / 40`

Doing that is quite simple though, just replace it with

```
salary = float(raw_input("What is your annual salary?")
```

You did that on the next line, so it looks like you know how to do it. In that case it is a matter of debugging your code. When you get an error, before you post it here, thoroughly look through each line in your code, especially stuff involved in the error message. I am sure with a little more effort, you could have caught that yourself and saved lots of time.